# Float line menu/nav with different color options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I am trying to use [this menu](http://www.menucool.com/horizontal/menu-code?menu=1&skin=2&p=1) for my wordpress site.

I am just wondering how can I make the float line change color for each nav item hovered/selected, cos it is red (`background-color:#800; height:2px;`) for all at the moment.

This is what I am trying to achieve:
 
Menu 1 - the hovering float line is green,
 
Menu 2 - the float line is yellow, 
Menu 3 - red, menu4 - blue and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more "CSS" way to achieve this but with some javascript you can get something quite readable. With this approach, your pages will need to correctly initialize the float line (`.hightlight`) and the nav border (`#sses1 > ul`).

The ideal solution would be a class for each float lines but here's what I got with javascript only :

```
<!-- added individual classes for nav items -->
<div id="sse1">
  <div id="sses1">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="nav-item-1" href="?menu=1&skin=2&p=Javascript-Menus">Javascript Menus</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item-2" href="?menu=1&skin=2&p=Horizontal-Menus">Horizontal Menus</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-item-3" href="?menu=1&skin=2&p=Web-Menus">Web Menus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Before the body or window is loaded :

```
    function customHandleMenu() {
        // get nav selector
        var nav = $('#sses1 > ul');

        // get float line selector
        var floatLine = $('.highlight'); // .hightlight must exist at this point

        // get colors for the current page
        var defaultBGcolor = floatLine.css('background-color');
        var defaultBorderColor = floatLine.css('border-color');
        var defaultNavBorderColor = nav.css('border-bottom-color');


        // change background-color and border-color on mouseenter event

        $('.nav-item-1').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                setColors({floatColor:'#0f0', borderColor:'#0f0'});
            }
        });

        $('.nav-item-2').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                setColors({floatColor:'#ee0', borderColor:'#ee0'});
            }
        });

        $('.nav-item-3').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                setColors({floatColor:'#05f', borderColor:'#05f'});
            }
        });


        /*
           ...
        */

        // put back default colors on the mouseleave event
        $('#sses1 > ul > li').on({
            mouseleave: function() {
              setColors({floatColor:defaultBGcolor, borderColor:defaultNavBorderColor});
            }
        });

        function setColors(args) {
            if (typeof args.floatColor != "undefined") {
                floatLine.css('background-color', args.floatColor);
            }

            if (typeof args.borderColor != "undefined") {
                floatLine.css('border-color', args.borderColor);
                nav.css('border-bottom-color', args.borderColor);
            }
        }
    }
```

To ensure that the selector is only use once .highlight exists, I suggest to modify the end of the original javascript to this:

```
function initMenu() {
    sse1.builMenu();
    customHandleMenu();
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", initMenu, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", initMenu);
}
else {
    window["onload"] = initMenu;
}
```

Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aRRD3/5/).

P.S.: the event chain is slighly modified to fit into jsfiddle.

Comment: There is no underline being used in this menu. It works by creating an `li` with `border-bottom` set.

Comment: sorry, thought I'd read about underline, ill update accordingly

Comment: Hi, it must be placed where the "hightlight" element is already defined. I will update for the hover out colors.

Comment: edited, please update your downvote since it now answers the OPs question thank you

Comment: Sorry Frederik I'm still not making it work, is it possible for you to point out which line of the javascript file I shall insert those code of yours, eg line 100 or any line of code? Thanks. I didn't mark you down, but I will give you an up vote anyhow to be fair. thanks.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it is still not working, everytime I put your code in, the whole menu shifts to the left and there is not float line any more. Can you look into it further if possible? Your help is reaaly appreciated. In the mean time I will keep trying. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you :) You are a legend. Just one question2. Sorry I prob didn't explain myself very well. When you selected nav1 or on nav 1 page, is it possible for nav 1 float line to stay as #0f0 color, selected nav2 or on nav 2 page, the float line is #ee0, nav 3 - #05f. Thanks heaps!

Comment: You will need to deal with it on the server side with PHP, for example. Make the server check the current page and put the correct style/colors according to it.

Comment: Is there any way to do it through javascript? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is possible to update styles and colors with javascript at the runtime by checking window.location.href, but this solution isn't optimal

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is actually non-trivial.   The author of the plugin is actually animating an li element's, "li.highlight", width and left positioning based on where you hover the mouse.  You can easily change the color of this thing by altering the CSS definition for this item.  For example to make it yellow, just include this css definition below the menu's css file:

```
#sses1 li.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 36px;
    height: 2px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px yellow;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I know this isn't the complete solution... but, if you're ambitious you could alter the javascript add a new class depending on which li element the .highlight element is under.

Comment: Hi Joeltine, thanks for your reply. Sorry but it is not what Im after to change the background to yellow. I'd like different float line colors for each menu item hovered and selected, eg hover item1, float line is yellow, item two floating line is green and so on. I will need to alter the javescript somehow, that's why I need some help. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I understood your problem.  I was trying to explain the solution is very involved.  But, I've given you the beginning of how to accomplish it.